# Object variable not set

Tags: vba, excel

I have a simple routine to copy data from a user-input sheet (Sheet1) to a protected sheet (Sheet2) for automatic workings. I'm having trouble debugging a simple line of code, just hoping someone can help me clear this one up :)

```
Sub CopyData()

Dim LastRowSh1 As Long
Dim LastColSh1 As Long
Dim Sheet1Data() As Variant
Dim LastRowSh2 As Long
Dim LastColSh2 As Long

    With Sheets("Sheet1")

        ' Defines data range in Sheet1.
        LastRowSh1 = .Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
        LastColSh1 = .Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
        ' Loads the contents of Sheet1 data into array Sheet1Data.
        Sheet1Data = .Range(.Cells(7, 1), .Cells(LastRowSh1, LastColSh1)).Value

    End With

    With Sheets("Sheet2")

        ' Removes any existing filters in Sheet2.
        If .AutoFilterMode = True Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData

        ' Defines preexisting data range in Sheet2 (if any).
        LastRowSh2 = .Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
```

I get Run-time error '91' on this line above. Can't for the life of me figure out why as it's the same `With` statement as above which is working just fine!

```
        LastColSh2 = .Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
        ' Clears preexisting data.
        .Range(.Cells(7, 1), .Cells(LastRowSh2, LastColSh2)).ClearContents

        ' Repopulates with the contents of array Sheet1Data.
        .Range(.Cells(7, 2), .Cells(LastRowSh1, LastColSh1 + 1)).Value = Sheet1Data

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are shortcutting your range references a bit too much. The `[A1]` you are using for the *After:=* parameter of the `Range.Find` method is insufficient to show parentage to the `With Sheets("Sheet2") ... End With`. Sheet1 is the *ActiveSheet* so that is the parent of `[A1]` and you cannot search *After:=Sheet1!A1* on Sheet2. If Sheet1 was *not* the active sheet, you would have the same problems in the `.Find` within `With Sheets("Sheet1") ... End With`.

You can prove this by using the following in the VBE's *Immediate Window*.

`?[A1].address(0,0,,True)`

Changing the active sheet in the workbook and re-running the command will change the worksheet name returned.

Just change the cell reference to something more appropriate like `.Cells(1,1)`.

```
LastRowSh2 = .Cells.Find("*", .Cells(1,1), , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
```

I'd recommend that you do this for both of the `Range.Find` code lines.